# How to set height of flex row but still allow row to expand vertically?

Tags: css, flexbox

Consider this very simple header:

```css
.box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <h1>This string needs to be able to wrap</h1>
</div>
```

The blue box needs to be defined by the height of the row and the text needs to be able to wrap. But as you can see, when the text wraps it extends beyond the flexbox. The flexbox can't grow at all because I have defined its height. If I remove the height specification then text wrap works correctly but the blue box disappears. This is a quite frustrating problem that I have spent hours trying to figure out. Is there no way to say to the row "your height is 60px but you can go bigger if you need to".

What I've tried so far:

- Use `min-height: 60px`. For some reason the blue box still doesn't show up when I do this.
- Use `max-height: 100px`. The row defaults to that size which is too big for when the text doesn't wrap.

I guess I could write media queries to manually change the height of the row, but it seems like there should be a more flexboxy way of doing this. Any ideas?

Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9uw67v4z/) if you want to play with it.

Comment: remove height:100% from box and the height from row, that's it

Comment: ^ flex-shrink:0 to the blue box if you want to keep the same width

Answer (score 1):

You don't need height: 100%; on child element of flex element.

And if you want minimum height of 60px on parent element, use `min-height: 60px;` instead of `height: 60px;`

```
.box {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 60px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/3bzeht52/